# Scala BigDecimal in a case class and forcing a MathContext

Tags: scala, functional-programming, bigdecimal, case-class

I am trying to create a `case class` that holds a `BigDecimal` as a value with a certain `MathContext` (RoundUp, Precision 2). The documentation said `BigDecimal.mc` is a `val`, so no simple reassignment. So I came up with two solutions. First this one

```
case class Test(number: BigDecimal)

object Test {
    def apply(n) = new Test(n, new java.math.MathContext(2))
}
```

I didn't like that one because it can be circumnavigated with the `new` keyword.

```
case class Test(var number: BigDecimal){
    number = BigDecimal(number.toString, new java.math.MathContext(2))
}
```

That second one works, but is ugly as hell and creates additional overhead. I am just wondering if I overlook something simple and elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about making the constructor private and thus forcing everyone to use `apply`?

```
// constructor is private - use apply instead!
case class MyBigDecimal private(number: BigDecimal)

object MyBigDecimal {
  private val defaultContext = new java.math.MathContext(2)

  def apply(number: BigDecimal) = new MyBigDecimal(BigDecimal(number.bigDecimal, defaultContext))
}
```

Also your second example could be re-written to be just ugly but not that inefficient:

```
case class MyBigDecimalWithVar(var number: BigDecimal) {
  number = BigDecimal(number.bigDecimal, new java.math.MathContext(2))
}
```

Comment: I like your solutions. I will use the first one. Thank you a lot.

Comment: For some reason, the option 1 of using apply didnot work for me. The option 2 however worked

Answer (score 2):

```
import scala.languageFeature.implicitConversions
import java.math.{MathContext, BigDecimal}

trait BigDecimalSpecial {
  def specialValue: BigDecimal
  def mathContext: MathContext
}

object BigDecimalSpecial {

  case class BigDecimalSpecial1(bd: BigDecimal) extends BigDecimalSpecial {
    val mathContext = new MathContext(2)
    val specialValue = new BigDecimal(bd.toString(), mathContext)
  }

  implicit def toBigDecimalSpecial1(bd: BigDecimal): BigDecimalSpecial = BigDecimalSpecial1(bd)

}

import BigDecimalSpecial._

val b = new BigDecimal("2.353453")
// b: java.math.BigDecimal = 2.353453

val forced = b.specialValue
// forced: java.math.BigDecimal = 2.4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It took me a while to understand what your code does, but now that I do, I don't think it solves my problem. In my `case class` that holds a `BigDecimal`, it still would have the wrong `MathContext` by default, won't it?